# How do I initialize this constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, initialization

I'm useing the rails console to run this code but I keep getting the error

NameError: uninitialized constant Subcategory::Subcategories

I've been trying to get this code to run for a while now but nothing I do is working.
here is the code that I'm using within the Subcategories_controller.rb

```
    def self.remove_subcat_when_expired
        Time.now == '21:00:00' ?

        nine_pm = Time.local(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, Date.today.day, 21, 0, 0)

        Subcategories.where("end_data <= #{nine_pm}").each do |subcategory|
        if (subcategory.end_date.today? and Time.now >= nine_pm) or subcategory.end_date < Date.Today
            subcategory.destroy
        end
    end
```

to run in rails console I'm using

```
 Subcategory.remove_subcat_when_expired
```

the line Subcategories.where("... is causing the problem, I need to initialize 'Subcategories' but I'm not sure how, any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try Subcategory.where("end_data <= #{nine_pm}")

Comment: I gave it a shot but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What *is* `Subcategories`? Do you actually have a class named that?

Comment: You can't be getting the same error if you don't reference `Subcategories`.

Comment: sorry I missread your suggestion. the error has changed a MySQL problem now
Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '21:00:00 +0100)' at line 1: SELECT `subcategories`.* FROM `subcategories`  WHERE (end_data <= 2013-10-25 21:00:00 +0100)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '21:00:00 +0100)' at line 1: SELECT `subcategories`.* FROM

Comment: not an answer, but don't use interpolations to build sql queries. This is a wide open door to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use instead: `where("end_data <= ?",nine_pm)` or `where(Subcategory.arel_table[:end_data].lteq nine_pm)`

Comment: duh, did not see you made the value yourself, so no risk here... sorry. Still, it's better to have good habits :)

Comment: used this line to fix the whole thing, thanks for all the suggestions and putting me on the right track guys '(subcategory.end_date.today? and Time.now >= nine_pm) or subcategory.end_date < Date.today'